# sending a document with description by telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a pdf document and a small description about it from my server to a Telegram group using a Telegram bot user. I'm able to send a document by itself using the method /sendDocument. However, that is not exactly what I want. I wonder is that even possible to do ?

```
curl -F chat_id="-xxxxxxxxxx" -F document=@"/home/telegram/someFile.pdf" -F text="Text Message with attachment" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sendDocument](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) method has a key `caption`. You need to put the description there.

```
curl -F chat_id="-xxxxxxxxxx" -F document=@"/home/telegram/someFile.pdf" -F caption="Text Message with attachment" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendDocument
```